# Start Amazon CloudWatch Agent at instance startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an Amazon Linux AMI Instance.

I installed CloudWatch Agent and start the service using this command.

```bash
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json -s
```

I can check the status of the CloudWatch Agent using this command and see that it's running

```bash
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -m ec2 -a status
```

However, I cannot find the service using

```bash
service amazon-cloudwatch-agent status
```

I want to set so that the CloudWatch Agent process start every time the instance starts. Something along the lines of `systemctl enable amazon-cloudwatch-agent`, but I don't have `systemctl` installed in my machine.

Is there any way I can setup so that the CloudWatch Agent starts every time the instance starts?

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service` worked for me on Ubuntu 22